Is Foreground Service the only option for running a single method?
I have an app that I have created where I want the app to run a single method when the the time reaches 00:00 (basically the next day).
For context, my app saves a csv file for each day. I've research around on how to make apps run in the background and foreground services was the the one that I found, but I feel like it is too overkill as my app will only run one method, once, each day (the method in question is the one that creates the csv file).
Is foreground services my only option or are there other ways to do this?

There may be useful ideas in Android Developer Guides like WorkManager or JobScheduler maybe(?)

I'll have a look at it. Thank you!

Don't forget to reset your alarm after boot: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Guide to selecting background task handler
Typically you'd want to use AlarmManager.
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent); //will call your YourBroadCastReceiver class once a day

YourBroadCastReceiver.java
public class YourBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  //your csv logic

    }
}

You also need to register YourBroadCastReceiver in the manifest, inside the <application> tag
<receiver
        android:name=".YourBroadCastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />


Do I need to put the first part of the code you have provided in my MainActivity.java class? To be specific, place it after the super.onCreate() line?

Yes, logically that ensures the code is run only once, depending on how the app is used.
