PendingIntent error in FLAG_MUTABLE and FLAG_IMMUTABLE
I am creating a java android application where my app runs a series of codes at midnight, everyday.
This is actually a continuation of my question here: Is Foreground Service the only option for running a single method? (under @Muzammal_Ghafoor's answer)
I have recreated the code that he gave me but now I came across a problem.

From the image above, it is stated that FLAG_MUTABLE or FLAG_IMMUTABLE must be specified when creating a PendingIntent. I am having a hard time understanding the documentation of PendingIntent so I have no idea how to fix this.
This is the code that I added from the answer that was given to me. For context, the PendingIntent is located on the scheduleDailyTask() function.
MainActivity.java // onCreate()
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        scheduleDailyTask(this);
}

MainActivity.java // scheduleDailyTask()
    public void scheduleDailyTask(Context context){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        // Alarm Schedule
        if (pendingIntent == null) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); // 1 = next day

            // Set the alarm to trigger at midnight every day
            alarmManager.setRepeating(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            );
        }
    }

DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver.java
public class DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        storage.createNewDailyCSV(context);
    }
}

storage.java // createNewDailyCSV()
    public static void createNewDailyCSV(Context context){
        try {
            // This creates the directories needed for the file
            ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
            Date dayToday = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String year = DayData.formatYEAR(dayToday);
            String month = DayData.formatMONTH(dayToday);
            dailyFileName = DayData.formatDAY(dayToday);
            dailyFilePath = new File(contextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(year + "/" + month), dailyFileName);

            // This creates the CSV and adds all the needed information inside it
            loadConstCSV();
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(dailyFilePath);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String name;
            String price;
            String weekday = DayData.formatWEEKDAY(dayToday);
            boolean[] weekdayBOOL;
            for (int i=0; i<Data.constantList.size();i++){
                name = Data.constantList.get(i).getName();
                price = String.valueOf(Data.constantList.get(i).getPrice());
                weekdayBOOL = Data.constantList.get(i).getWd_Bool();
                switch (weekday){
                    case "Sun":
                        if (weekdayBOOL[0]){
                            sb.append(name).append(",").append(price).append("\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Mon":
                        if (weekdayBOOL[1]){
                            sb.append(name).append(",").append(price).append("\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Tue":
                        if (weekdayBOOL[2]){
                            sb.append(name).append(",").append(price).append("\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Wed":
                        if (weekdayBOOL[3]){
                            sb.append(name).append(",").append(price).append("\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Thu":
                        if (weekdayBOOL[4]){
                            sb.append(name).append(",").append(price).append("\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Fri":
                        if (weekdayBOOL[5]){
                            sb.append(name).append(",").append(price).append("\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Sat":
                        if (weekdayBOOL[6]){
                            sb.append(name).append(",").append(price).append("\n");
                        }
                        break;
                }
                outputFile.write(sb.toString());
                outputFile.close();
            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            Data.constantList.clear();
        }
    }
}


Please update your code in the scheduleDailyTask() and try to compile the project.
  alarmManager.setRepeating(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            );

Note: If your project targeting 31 or above android version you must specify either the FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE.

Thank you! It compiled properly and I now have to wait until midnight to know if my code is working properly!

Hello! It is currently 12:02 AM right now and I checked my app data and the CSV wasn't created. For context I called the function storage.createNewDailyCSV(context);  in my DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver but it didn't create the CSV. I know my createCSV function works because I placed the same line on my MainActivity.java and it created a CSV file the moment I opened the app. How do I fix this?

Additional question, is there a way for me to test this without waiting until midnight? Just so that I know that the whole AlarmManager thing works?

There could be multiple factors involved in it. I suggest you schedule it after maybe 1 or 2 minutes and just verify first if is it triggering or not (You can simply print anything). Once you're sure that the schedule logic working fine then check your csv generation logic separately. And ultimately you can put them both together.

You can update your code to repeat after every 1 minute

@Akira updated the answer here you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78436569/is-foreground-service-the-only-option-for-running-a-single-method/78436845#78436845

Thank you thank you! I'll do this later then I will let you know if it works.

Hello! @Muzammal_Abdul_Ghafoor I changed the scheduleDailyTask to work every minute to test and everything works! It created the csv and the toast worked and appeared every minute. I think the problem lies in the // Alarm Schedule  if-statement.

I was thinking of letting it run every minute but I think that is overkill. I would still prefer the once a day method.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78452027/alarmmanager-not-working-properly-as-intended I created a new question because I found new problems.
