AlarmManager not working properly as intended
I want to create an app that runs a specific code one a day.
I asked here in stackOverflow and they told me that alarm manager is the right way to go. So i used it and came up with this.
AndroidManifest.xml (inside <application>)
<receiver android:name=".DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver" />

MainActivity.java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    scheduleDailyTask(this);
}

public void scheduleDailyTask(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE); //from FLAG_NO_CREATE to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

        //Made it repeat every minute for testing
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

        // Set the alarm to repeat every minute
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                60 * 1000, // 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds
                pendingIntent );
    }

DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver.java
public class DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "bomboclat minute has passed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        storage.createNewDailyCSV(context);
    }
}

Now, initially, everything worked just fine. The code runs and the toast worked every minute even though the application is not running on my phone. But when I run the app again  it doesn't work now.
I don't know what went wrong and I am lost.


Please be aware that setRepeating will not guarantee that your alarm will fire at the time specified. When using set repeating the OS can delay your alarm so that it fires with other alarms to help save battery life. If you need to repeat an alarm at an exact time every time you need to use setExact but that also brings up other issues such as additional permissions and setting the alarm again after the alarm went off

See documentation regarding my above comment https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Try adding the immutable flag

Why are you using Flag.NO_CREATE? This will not generate a PendingIntent for you if one doesn't already exist.

It sounds like the issue is that when the pendingIntent is not null (meaning the alarm is already set), the toast is not showing up. This could be because the BroadcastReceiver is not being triggered.
One possible reason for this could be that the BroadcastReceiver is being unregistered somewhere in your code, or the PendingIntent is being cancelled. Make sure that you're not doing either of these things in your code.
Another possible reason could be that the device is going to sleep and the BroadcastReceiver is not waking it up. To ensure that the device wakes up to receive the broadcast, you can use a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. Here's an example of how to use it:

Add the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'


Create a new class that extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

public class DailyTaskWakefulBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("DailyTaskWakefulBroadcastReceiver", "onReceive called");

        // Pass the intent to your existing BroadcastReceiver
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}


Modify your DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver to extend BroadcastReceiver instead of WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

public class DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver", "onReceive called");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Daily task has been triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Add your code here to run the task
    }
}


Modify your scheduleDailyTask method to use the DailyTaskWakefulBroadcastReceiver:

public void scheduleDailyTask(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DailyTaskWakefulBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

    // Check if the alarm is already set
    if (pendingIntent == null) {
        // Alarm is not set, set it
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        // Set the alarm to repeat every day at 12 AM
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        // If the current time is past 12 AM, set it for the next day
        if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);

        Log.d("DailyTaskScheduler", "Alarm has been set");
    } else {
        // Alarm is already set
        Log.d("DailyTaskScheduler", "Alarm already exists");
    }
}


Modify your AndroidManifest.xml file to use the DailyTaskWakefulBroadcastReceiver:

<receiver android:name=".DailyTaskWakefulBroadcastReceiver" />
<receiver android:name=".DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver" />

This should ensure that the device wakes up to receive the broadcast and your BroadcastReceiver is triggered.

app is not allowed to run when PendingIntent doesn't have FLAG_MUTABLE or FLAG_IMMUTABLE

I can't insert image so I'll edit the question and insert the image there.

Nevermind It doesn't work now. Based on my observation, it only works once then after that it doesn't. I waited for 5 minutes and it only toasted once, and that is only on the first minute. Is it always like that? shouldn't it toast every minute?

you can use  FLAG_MUTABLE or FLAG_IMMUTABLE  , but make sure  that you do not create  everytime  scheduleDailyTask
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

It still doesn't work :/ under my DailyTaskBroadcastReceiver, I added a toast line so that I know that it is being called every minute, but It doesn't do that.

instead of  alarmManager.setRepeating use alarmManager.setInexactRepeating

Nevermind, I take back what I said that it works, it doesn't work again. However, this is what I found out. I added printlns inside the if-statement on scheduleDailyTask() to see if the alarm exists or not. If pendingIntent is null, it prints "Alarm has been set", it creates an alarm, which then makes the toast every minute work. BUT, if the pendingIntent is not null, it prints "Alarm already exists", the toast then doesn't work.

use  WakefulBroadcastReceiver

there are two build.gradle.kts file in my project. (on for Project:AppName and Module:app).  if I copy-paste the code you have given in
dependencies {     implementation(libs.appcompat) (there are more here) }
It gets an error "Unresolved Reference". The text "implementation" is highlighted in red, while the 'com.google...' string has a red underline that says unexpected token.
